# JNI Unable to call CallVoidMethod

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a requirement to make a call from C++ to Java using JNI and invoke a void method in MainActivity.
I do not have the JavaVM argument to pass to the JNI layer in this case. So I am using env->NewGlobalRef like below and retriving it by (g_javaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL)
I am getting an error while trying to invoke CallVoidMethod as jobject service = env->NewObject(jobj, ctor) results in NULL service.
Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

```
JavaVM* g_javaVM = nullptr;
jclass cls;
jclass jobj;
jint JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM* vm, void* reserved ) {
  JNIEnv* env;
  if( vm->GetEnv( reinterpret_cast<void**>( &env ), JNI_VERSION_1_6 ) != JNI_OK ) {
        return -1;
    }
  cls = env->FindClass("com/test/MainActivity");
  jobj = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(cls);
  g_javaVM = vm;
  return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void NativeLib::play() {
   JNIEnv *env;
   jint rs = (g_javaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
   assert(rs == JNI_OK);
   jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(jobj, "<init>", "()V");
   jmethodID jobj_play= env->GetMethodID(jobj,"play","()V");
   jobject service = env->NewObject(jobj, ctor); //Getting error on this line. service is NULL
   env->CallVoidMethod(service, jobj_play);
}
```

Comment: Is `MainActivity` an Android `Activity`? You're not supposed to create those by calling their constructor.

Comment: Yes it's Android Activity. I was testing by adding the play method in MainActivity but I can add it in another class too.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the issue. I used another class instead of MainActivity and it's working now. Can you put this as an answer and I can accept it?